# Finite State Machine For Java-Based Crowd Simulation

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a crowd simulation using Java. I have split my application based on the MVC framework. I have used a flocking algorithm to model the people's movements. Now I need the groups of people to move along a set pathway. I am attempting to do this using an FSM but need some extra guidance.

Each group of passengers is formed from an ArrayList with a small triangular symbol representing each passenger.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import utility.Vector2d;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class Flock2 {
public ArrayList<BusinessPersonBoid> boids2;
private double movementFactor = 1000;       
private double boundingFactor = 10;         
private int seperationDistance = 43;        
private double seperationFactor = 50;   


Circle c = new Circle();
Circle c2 = new Circle();


public Flock2() {
    boids2 = new ArrayList<BusinessPersonBoid>();


    Random randNum = new Random();
    RandomName randName = new RandomName();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int  x = randNum.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        int  y = randNum.nextInt(400) + 1;

        boids2.add(new BusinessPersonBoid(x,y, randName.getName(), c ));
    } 

} 


public void updateBoidsPostion() {
    Vector2d v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = new Vector2d();
    for (BusinessPersonBoid cBoid : boids2) {

        Path path = new Path();
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(-50,140));
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(150,140));
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(750,140));
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(910,-40));

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();

        pathTransition.setPath(path);
        pathTransition.setNode(cBoid);



    v1 = groupFlock(cBoid);
    v2 = collisionAvoidance(cBoid);
    v3 = matchFlockVelocity(cBoid);
    v4 = bounding(cBoid);
    v5 = positionTend(cBoid);




    Vector2d sum = new Vector2d();
    sum = sum.add(v1);
    sum = sum.add(v2);
    sum = sum.add(v3);
    sum = sum.add(v4);
    sum = sum.add(v5);




    cBoid.setVelocity(cBoid.getVelocity().add(sum));
    Vector2d next = new Vector2d( cBoid.getPosition().add(cBoid.getVelocity()) );
    cBoid.setPosition(next);
    Vector2d next2 = new Vector2d( cBoid.getPosition().add(cBoid.getVelocity()) );





    pathTransition.play();


    }
}


private Vector2d groupFlock(BusinessPersonBoid cBoid) {
    Vector2d center = new Vector2d();

    for (BusinessPersonBoid aBoid : boids2) {
        if(!aBoid.equals(cBoid)) {
            center = center.add(aBoid.getPosition());
        }
    }
    center = center.division(boids2.size() - 1 );
    center = center.subtract(cBoid.getPosition());
    center = center.division(movementFactor);

    return center;   
}


private Vector2d collisionAvoidance(BusinessPersonBoid cBoid) {
    Vector2d correction = new Vector2d();
    Vector2d cPosition = new Vector2d(cBoid.getPosition());

    for (BusinessPersonBoid aBoid : boids2) {
        if (!aBoid.equals(cBoid)) {
            Vector2d aPosition = aBoid.getPosition();
            Vector2d xD = new Vector2d(aPosition.xPos - cPosition.xPos, aPosition.yPos - cPosition.yPos);

            if(Math.abs(xD.xPos) < seperationDistance && Math.abs(xD.yPos) < seperationDistance) {  
                correction = correction.subtract(xD).division(seperationFactor);
            }

        }
}
return correction;
}


private Vector2d matchFlockVelocity(BusinessPersonBoid cBoid) {
    Vector2d perceivedVelocity = new Vector2d();

    for(BusinessPersonBoid aBoid : boids2) {
        if(!aBoid.equals(cBoid)) {
            perceivedVelocity = perceivedVelocity.add(aBoid.getVelocity());
        }
    }
    perceivedVelocity = perceivedVelocity.division(boids2.size() - 1);
    perceivedVelocity = perceivedVelocity.subtract(cBoid.getVelocity());
    perceivedVelocity = perceivedVelocity.division(8);
    return perceivedVelocity;
}


private Vector2d bounding(BusinessPersonBoid cBoid) {
    Vector2d bound = new Vector2d();

    int xMin = 0, xMax = 1400, yMin = 0, yMax = 320;

    Vector2d cPos = cBoid.getPosition();

    if (cPos.xPos < xMin) {
         bound.xPos += 1;
         cPos.xPos = bound.xPos;
    } else if (cPos.xPos > xMax){
        bound.xPos += -100;
        cPos.xPos = bound.xPos;
    }
    if (cPos.yPos < yMin) {
         bound.yPos += 1;
         cPos.yPos = bound.yPos;
    } else if (cPos.yPos > yMax){
        bound.yPos += -100;
        cPos.yPos = bound.yPos;
    }

    bound = bound.division(boundingFactor);

    return bound;
}


private Vector2d positionTend(BusinessPersonBoid cBoid) {
    Vector2d place = new Vector2d(900,600); 
    Vector2d tend = new Vector2d();

    tend = new Vector2d(place.subtract(cBoid.getPosition()));
    tend.division(6000);        
    return tend;
}


public List<ImageView> getBoidsRepresentation() {
    List<ImageView> circles = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
    for(BusinessPersonBoid aBoid : boids2) {
        circles.add( aBoid.getDisplay() );
    }
    return circles;
}


private Vector2d bounding2(BusinessPersonBoid cBoid) {
    Vector2d bound = new Vector2d();

    int xMin = 0, xMax = 600, yMin = 0, yMax = 600;

    Vector2d cPos = cBoid.getPosition();


         bound.xPos = 100;
         cPos.xPos = bound.xPos;

         bound.yPos = 100;
         cPos.yPos = bound.yPos;


    bound = bound.division(boundingFactor);

    return bound;
}
```

This is my attempt at changing the pathway:

```
private Vector2d pathway(BusinessPersonBoid cBoid) {
    Vector2d pathway = new Vector2d();

    Path path = new Path();
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(20,20));
    path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(380, 0, 380, 120, 200, 120));
    path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(0, 120, 0, 240, 380, 240));
    PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
    pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
    pathTransition.setPath(path);
    pathTransition.setNode(cBoid);


  return pathway;
}
```

Currently, it is having no effect on the overall pathway which the boids take. They need to move from one area of the screen to another as a group, but retain the random movements within that group.

My question is what would be the best method to move the boids from one area of the screen to another while retaining the random movements within the group of boids?

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question. Please add one.

Comment: I can't comment on "best" method, but try to encode boid position as relative to position of the group, so that the group moves as a whole, and since boid moves relative to the group, it will have to move the same direction as well, but it could then also move randomly around center of mass.

Comment: Or you can have a boid "respond" to movement of a group after a while, so its movement will not be entirely random.